# How can I validate reactive form controls programmatically?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a `FormGroup` object of my reactive form. Now I want to trigger the form validation programmatically.

I already check the form with this code, but my control css status classes aren't set, like it's done when I click the control and click outside the control.

```js
if (!this.formGroup.valid) {
  // TODO: Fix that invalid controls don't get highlighted
  return;
}
```

Comment: Not sure the CSS has to do with that, but try `this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity()`.

Comment: I tested, and it doesn't trigger my css status classes

Comment: As said, I don't think your CSS issue has to do with the form validation. I think that the detection provided isn't what suits you best. Let me give you a suited answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can programmatically trigger the validator using the following.

```js
this.formGroup.controls['controlNameHere'].markAsTouched();
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create a reactive form, you implicitly says that the form should update its values and validity on a specific strategy.

There are 3 strategies :

- On blur
- On change
- On submit

You can change the update strategy when you create your form controls or your form group. In your case, the change strategy should work.

[Here is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upcem3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) containing both strategies, see what suits you best.

```js
first = new FormControl('', {
  validators: [Validators.minLength(3)],
  updateOn: 'blur'
})
second = new FormControl('', {
  validators: [Validators.minLength(3)],
  updateOn: 'change'
})
```

Comment: this is a nice simple approach to adding maxLength validation to a specific formControl input and per the stackblitz you shared an easy way to throw the validation error in the HTML `<div class="error" *ngIf="first.hasError('maxlength')">Task can be max 40 characters long.</div>`

Answer (score 3):

**Validate all form fields**

```
validateAllFormFields(formGroup: FormGroup) {
  Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
    const control = formGroup.get(field);

    if (control instanceof FormControl) {
      control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
    } 
    else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
      this.validateAllFormFields(control);
    }
  });
}
```